# Mitered Tile Edge Trim around Niche in Shower... Will water get behind it?

Tags: water, tile, leak, trim

I'm wondering what the proper way to install tile edge trim around a shower niche is.

Some people leave space for grout in between the mitered edges and some people don't (*see pictures for example of both*).  It seems to me that leaving space for grout is the correct way so water will not seep through and get behind tile.

But perhaps it does not matter as I see more examples of people not leaving any space for grout in the mitered ends.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image: niche]

Comment: As you've seen multiple examples of both, I would think that both will work just fine. If you're doing it yourself, I'd suggest leaving a grout joint as your cuts are likely to not be quite as accurate as a pro's would be (practice makes _nearly_ perfect!) and the grout joint will help hide the fact that your cuts aren't a perfect 45° and maybe one came out a smidge short. If you're hiring it out, I'd suggest going with the way you prefer, then talk to your installer about it to ensure he can/will do it that way.

Comment: I agree leaving room for grout lines would be easier but I'm fairly skilled and I'm not worried about the difficulty.  I prefer the look of the mitered ends being tight to each other but am worried it will leak water behind tile

Comment: TBH, your example of "groutless" looks like it's actually aluminum/stainless steel and was probably applied with a silicone adhesive which also sealed the joints. If you're doing it with actual tile (that's a _super_ thin piece to cut/break), you could probably squeeze in a bead of silicone along the miter when installing to ensure no water gets behind it.

Comment: Grout does not stop water from passing through it. Some Water WILL get behind it regardless.  The niche as well as the rest of the wall needs to have a water proof membrane.

Comment: I did apply red guard to waterproof. I did not know grout wasn’t waterproof however. Good to know, thanks!